# Jar file with openCV and javafx

Tags: java, opencv

I made a rubiks cube application which includes a cube detection system, As im getting closer to wrapping up the project I wanted to make a JAR file. I get errors when running the JAR file and it really sucks because I can only run the project in IntelliJ(IDE).
I face two problems:
1) I cant get the JAR to link openCV properly
2)I have a problem loading an FXML file(this will occur assuming it did not crash while trying to load openCV.

For case 1 here is the code and errors:

```
static {
   // try {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
 //   } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
   //     System.err.println("Could not find OpenCV Library!");
 //   }
}
```

and the error message:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java342 in java.library.path:
```

Now If i remove the try catch comments i get this error:

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
       System.err.println("Could not find OpenCV Library!");
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    //Loader
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(main.class.getResource("FXML_layouts\\MainScreen.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
    ((mainController)loader.getController()).setStage(primaryStage);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Error:

```
    Could not find OpenCV Library!
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
```

Here is my file structure:
[image]

and here is my artifact config:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with the steps below:

1. Put the `opencv_java342.dll` in a folder let call it `dll_libs` in a
   drive e.g `C:\dll_libs`
2. Then go to Environment Variable -> Edit path -> put `C:\dll_libs` ->
   Apply -> OK
3. Restart your IDE

**OR:** Just put the `opencv_java342.dll` file in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder

And it is : )

**Update (for your second question):** If you want to give the executable package to someone else to run the program, there are almost 2 ways:

1. Let them to create the environment manually, just as the answer to
   your question.
2. Do the job programmatically, just within your code write a function
   which set the .dd environment variable on the program startup, and
   then load the lib.

If you choose the second one, here I will give an example code to refere to:

```
public static void loadOpenCVLib() throws Exception {
    File file = new File(OpenCVUtil.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    File opencv_libs = new File("oc_lib"); // this path is where is the lib going to copy to
    String model = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
    String localLibPath; // this is the path inside your program resource
    if (model.equals("64")) {
        localLibPath = "oc_lib/64bit";
    } else {
        localLibPath = "oc_lib/x86";
    }
    if (file.isFile()) { // when run from jar
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(file);
        if (!opencv_libs.exists() || !opencv_libs.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                JarUtils.copyResourcesToDirectory(jar, localLibPath, opencv_libs.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to create load opencv libs!!");
            }
        } else {
            String[] list = opencv_libs.list();
            if (list != null && list.length != 2) {
                try {
                    JarUtils.copyResourcesToDirectory(jar, localLibPath, opencv_libs.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new IOException("Failed to create load opencv libs!!");
                }
            }
        }
    } else { // when run from IDE
        File libPath = new File(OpenCVUtil.class.getResource("/"+localLibPath).getFile());
        if (!opencv_libs.exists() || !opencv_libs.isDirectory()) {
            boolean isDone = opencv_libs.mkdir();
            if (!isDone && !opencv_libs.exists()) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to create load opencv libs!!");
            }
            try {
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(libPath, opencv_libs);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to create load opencv libs!!");
            }
        } else {
            String[] list1 = opencv_libs.list();
            String[] list2 = libPath.list();
            boolean contentEquals = list1 != null && list2 != null && list1.length == list2.length;
            if (contentEquals) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.copyDirectory(libPath, opencv_libs);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new IOException("Failed to create load opencv libs!!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", opencv_libs.getAbsolutePath());
    Field sys_paths = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
    sys_paths.setAccessible(true);
    sys_paths.set(null, null);
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    // it is for the ffmpeg name
    String[] list = opencv_libs.list();
    assert list != null;
    String ffmpeg_dll_file_name = null;
    for (String s : list) {
        if (s.contains("ffmpeg")) {
            ffmpeg_dll_file_name = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("."));
        }
    }
    System.loadLibrary(ffmpeg_dll_file_name);
}
```

Hope it can help!!

Comment: I did this, The first method worked but now Im still facing the second problem with loading resources. In addition, If i want to send this to a friend they will have to set their environmental variables as well. there has to be a better alternative...

Comment: @ItayBachar If the answer solved your problem, then first of all as the regular accept and vote up the answer and then we will go to the next problem, Thanks!

Comment: @ItayBachar Now you can check the answer for your second question.